# How to use substring with criteria builder

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, substring, criteria

I want to convert string `11.0.3.200` to `0011.0000.0003.0200` for sorting this String descending.

```
Expression<String> majorVer = cb.function("SUBSTRING_INDEX", String.class, uf.get(sortAttr), cb.literal("."), cb.literal(1)); //11      
Expression<String> lpadMajorValue = cb.function("lpad", String.class, majorVer, cb.literal(4), cb.literal("0"));

Expression<String> minorVerBase = cb.function("REPLACE", String.class, uf.get(sortAttr), cb.concat(majorVer, cb.literal(".")), cb.literal(""));//0.3.200      
Expression<String> minorVer = cb.function("SUBSTRING_INDEX", String.class, minorVerBase, cb.literal("."), cb.literal(1)); //0
 Expression<String> lpadMinorValue = cb.function("lpad", String.class, minorVer, cb.literal(4), cb.literal("0"));

Expression<String> buildVerBase = cb.function("REPLACE", String.class, minorVerBase, cb.concat(minorVer, cb.literal(".")), cb.literal("")); //3.200
Expression<String> buildVer = cb.function("SUBSTRING_INDEX", String.class, buildVerBase, cb.literal("."), cb.literal(1)); //3
Expression<String> lpadBuildValue = cb.function("lpad", String.class, buildVer, cb.literal(4), cb.literal("0"));

Expression<String> revVer = cb.function("REPLACE", String.class, buildVerBase, cb.concat(buildVer, cb.literal(".")), cb.literal("")); //200
Expression<String> lpadRevisionValue = cb.function("lpad", String.class, revVer, cb.literal(4), cb.literal("0"));

Expression<String> lpadValue = cb.concat(lpadMajorValue, cb.concat(lpadMinorValue, cb.concat(lpadBuildValue, lpadRevisionValue)));

 orderList.add(cb.desc(lpadValue));
```

But I am getting an exception:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function substring_index(text) does not exist"
```

Any suggestion if I am doing something wrong with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` use with criteria build. If `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is not supported by criteria builder what is the alternative?

Comment: PostgreSQL says "function substring_index(text) does not exist". So there is no such function. So don't use it and use something else. MySQL has that function but you apparently aren't using MySQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Where in the [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) did you find `substring_index()`?

Comment: Even function SPLIT_PART is present in the link given above but still it is giving same exception and saying ERROR: function split_part(text) does not exist

Comment: which is where you look at the SQL invoked!!! aka debugging

Answer (score 0):

Section 4.6.17.2 of the JPA 2.2 specification lists the functions available in JPA and it does not include `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. I guess it is safe to assume that earlier versions don't include it either. Therefore JPA won't be able to translate it into something database specific.

It also isn't part of Postgres' SQL dialect. So the simple passthrough doesn't work either, as you noticed.

Fortunately, JPA knows about `LOCATE` which sounds like what you are looking for.

From the specification:

> The LOCATE function returns the position of a given string within a string, starting the search at a spec- ified position. It returns the first position at which the string was found as an integer. The first argument is the string to be located; the second argument is the string to be searched; the optional third argument is an integer that represents the string position at which the search is started (by default, the beginning of the string to be searched). The first position in a string is denoted by 1. If the string is not found, 0 is returned.